# Como separar el mensaje de error de el Float Label

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html5, bootstrap

Tengo un formulario donde se pueden ingresar datos, validación de campos requeridos, Cuando selecciono el TextBox para insertar texto, la propiedad PlaceHolder se coloca como titulo del TextBox (FloatLabel), Pero esos textBox Validan que se tienen que ingresar datos, asi que me muestra el mensaje de la siguiente Forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta aqui todo Bien, el problema es que cuando selecciono el textBox que me muestra es error, pasa lo siguiente con el FloatLabel:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver se juntan los "mensajes", que debo hacer?

Nota: Estoy Usando Bootstrap v3.3.6

```js
/*! jQuery Validation Plugin - v1.13.0 - 7/1/2014
 * http://jqueryvalidation.org/
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Jörn Zaefferer; Licensed MIT */
!function(a){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],a):a(jQuery)}(function(a){a.extend(a.fn,{validate:function(b){if(!this.length)return void(b&&b.debug&&window.console&&console.warn("Nothing selected, can't validate, returning nothing."));var c=a.data(this[0],"validator");return c?c:(this.attr("novalidate","novalidate"),c=new a.validator(b,this[0]),a.data(this[0],"validator",c),c.settings.onsubmit&&(this.validateDelegate(":submit","click",function(b){c.settings.submitHandler&&(c.submitButton=b.target),a(b.target).hasClass("cancel")&&(c.cancelSubmit=!0),void 0!==a(b.target).attr("formnovalidate")&&(c.cancelSubmit=!0)}),this.submit(function(b){function d(){var d;return c.settings.submitHandler?(c.submitButton&&(d=a("<input type='hidden'/>").attr("name",c.submitButton.name).val(a(c.submitButton).val()).appendTo(c.currentForm)),c.settings.submitHandler.call(c,c.currentForm,b),c.submitButton&&d.remove(),!1):!0}return c.settings.debug&&b.preventDefault(),c.cancelSubmit?(c.cancelSubmit=!1,d()):c.form()?c.pendingRequest?(c.formSubmitted=!0,!1):d():(c.focusInvalid(),!1)})),c)},valid:function(){var b,c;return a(this[0]).is("form")?b=this.validate().form():(b=!0,c=a(this[0].form).validate(),this.each(function(){b=c.element(this)&&b})),b},removeAttrs:function(b){var c={},d=this;return a.each(b.split(/\s/),function(a,b){c[b]=d.attr(b),d.removeAttr(b)}),c},rules:function(b,c){var d,e,f,g,h,i,j=this[0];if(b)switch(d=a.data(j.form,"validator").settings,e=d.rules,f=a.validator.staticRules(j),b){case"add":a.extend(f,a.validator.normalizeRule(c)),delete f.messages,e[j.name]=f,c.messages&&(d.messages[j.name]=a.extend(d.messages[j.name],c.messages));break;case"remove":return c?(i={},a.each(c.split(/\s/),function(b,c){i[c]=f[c],delete f[c],"required"===c&&a(j).removeAttr("aria-required")}),i):(delete e[j.name],f)}return g=a.validator.normalizeRules(a.extend({},a.validator.classRules(j),a.validator.attributeRules(j),a.validator.dataRules(j),a.validator.staticRules(j)),j),g.required&&(h=g.required,delete g.required,g=a.extend({required:h},g),a(j).attr("aria-required","true")),g.remote&&(h=g.remote,delete g.remote,g=a.extend(g,{remote:h})),g}}),a.extend(a.expr[":"],{blank:function(b){return!a.trim(""+a(b).val())},filled:function(b){return!!a.trim(""+a(b).val())},unchecked:function(b){return!a(b).prop("checked")}}),a.validator=function(b,c){this.settings=a.extend(!0,{},a.validator.defaults,b),this.currentForm=c,this.init()},a.validator.format=function(b,c){return 1===arguments.length?function(){var c=a.makeArray(arguments);return c.unshift(b),a.validator.format.apply(this,c)}:(arguments.length>2&&c.constructor!==Array&&(c=a.makeArray(arguments).slice(1)),c.constructor!==Array&&(c=[c]),a.each(c,function(a,c){b=b.replace(new RegExp("\\{"+a+"\\}","g"),function(){return c})}),b)},a.extend(a.validator,{defaults:{messages:{},groups:{},rules:{},errorClass:"error",validClass:"valid",errorElement:"label",focusInvalid:!0,errorContainer:a([]),errorLabelContainer:a([]),onsubmit:!0,ignore:":hidden",ignoreTitle:!1,onfocusin:function(a){this.lastActive=a,this.settings.focusCleanup&&!this.blockFocusCleanup&&(this.settings.unhighlight&&this.settings.unhighlight.call(this,a,this.settings.errorClass,this.settings.validClass),this.hideThese(this.errorsFor(a)))},onfocusout:function(a){this.checkable(a)||!(a.name in this.submitted)&&this.optional(a)||this.element(a)},onkeyup:function(a,b){(9!==b.which||""!==this.elementValue(a))&&(a.name in this.submitted||a===this.lastElement)&&this.element(a)},onclick:function(a){a.name in this.submitted?this.element(a):a.parentNode.name in this.submitted&&this.element(a.parentNode)},highlight:function(b,c,d){"radio"===b.type?this.findByName(b.name).addClass(c).removeClass(d):a(b).addClass(c).removeClass(d)},unhighlight:function(b,c,d){"radio"===b.type?this.findByName(b.name).removeClass(c).addClass(d):a(b).removeClass(c).addClass(d)}},setDefaults:function(b){a.extend(a.validator.defaults,b)},messages:{required:"Este campo es requerido.",remote:"Please fix this field.",email:"Ingrese una dirección e-mail válida",direccion:"Ingrese una dirección válida",url:"Please enter a valid URL.",date:"Please enter a valid date.",dateISO:"Please enter a valid date ( ISO ).",number:"Por favor ingrese un número válido",texto:"Ingrese solo letras",digits:"Ingrese solo números.",creditcard:"Please enter a valid credit card number.",equalTo:"El valor no corresponde",maxlength:a.validator.format("Please enter no more than {0} characters."),minlength:a.validator.format("Please enter at least {0} characters."),rangelength:a.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1} characters long."),range:a.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1}."),max:a.validator.format("Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}."),min:a.validator.format("Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}.")},autoCreateRanges:!1,prototype:{init:function(){function b(b){var c=a.data(this[0].form,"validator"),d="on"+b.type.replace(/^validate/,""),e=c.settings;e[d]&&!this.is(e.ignore)&&e[d].call(c,this[0],b)}this.labelContainer=a(this.settings.errorLabelContainer),this.errorContext=this.labelContainer.length&&this.labelContainer||a(this.currentForm),this.containers=a(this.settings.errorContainer).add(this.settings.errorLabelContainer),this.submitted={},this.valueCache={},this.pendingRequest=0,this.pending={},this.invalid={},this.reset();var c,d=this.groups={};a.each(this.settings.groups,function(b,c){"string"==typeof c&&(c=c.split(/\s/)),a.each(c,function(a,c){d[c]=b})}),c=this.settings.rules,a.each(c,function(b,d){c[b]=a.validator.normalizeRule(d)}),a(this.currentForm).validateDelegate(":text, [type='password'], [type='file'], select, textarea, [type='number'], [type='search'] ,[type='tel'], [type='url'], [type='email'], [type='datetime'], [type='date'], [type='month'], [type='week'], [type='time'], [type='datetime-local'], [type='range'], [type='color'], [type='radio'], [type='checkbox']","focusin focusout keyup",b).validateDelegate("select, option, [type='radio'], [type='checkbox']","click",b),this.settings.invalidHandler&&a(this.currentForm).bind("invalid-form.validate",this.settings.invalidHandler),a(this.currentForm).find("[required], [data-rule-required], .required").attr("aria-required","true")},form:function(){return this.checkForm(),a.extend(this.submitted,this.errorMap),this.invalid=a.extend({},this.errorMap),this.valid()||a(this.currentForm).triggerHandler("invalid-form",[this]),this.showErrors(),this.valid()},checkForm:function(){this.prepareForm();for(var a=0,b=this.currentElements=this.elements();b[a];a++)this.check(b[a]);return this.valid()},element:function(b){var c=this.clean(b),d=this.validationTargetFor(c),e=!0;return this.lastElement=d,void 0===d?delete this.invalid[c.name]:(this.prepareElement(d),this.currentElements=a(d),e=this.check(d)!==!1,e?delete this.invalid[d.name]:this.invalid[d.name]=!0),a(b).attr("aria-invalid",!e),this.numberOfInvalids()||(this.toHide=this.toHide.add(this.containers)),this.showErrors(),e},showErrors:function(b){if(b){a.extend(this.errorMap,b),this.errorList=[];for(var c in b)this.errorList.push({message:b[c],element:this.findByName(c)[0]});this.successList=a.grep(this.successList,function(a){return!(a.name in b)})}this.settings.showErrors?this.settings.showErrors.call(this,this.errorMap,this.errorList):this.defaultShowErrors()},resetForm:function(){a.fn.resetForm&&a(this.currentForm).resetForm(),this.submitted={},this.lastElement=null,this.prepareForm(),this.hideErrors(),this.elements().removeClass(this.settings.errorClass).removeData("previousValue").removeAttr("aria-invalid")},numberOfInvalids:function(){return this.objectLength(this.invalid)},objectLength:function(a){var b,c=0;for(b in a)c++;return c},hideErrors:function(){this.hideThese(this.toHide)},hideThese:function(a){a.not(this.containers).text(""),this.addWrapper(a).hide()},valid:function(){return 0===this.size()},size:function(){return this.errorList.length},focusInvalid:function(){if(this.settings.focusInvalid)try{a(this.findLastActive()||this.errorList.length&&this.errorList[0].element||[]).filter(":visible").focus().trigger("focusin")}catch(b){}},findLastActive:function(){var b=this.lastActive;return b&&1===a.grep(this.errorList,function(a){return a.element.name===b.name}).length&&b},elements:function(){var b=this,c={};return a(this.currentForm).find("input, select, textarea").not(":submit, :reset, :image, [disabled]").not(this.settings.ignore).filter(function(){return!this.name&&b.settings.debug&&window.console&&console.error("%o has no name assigned",this),this.name in c||!b.objectLength(a(this).rules())?!1:(c[this.name]=!0,!0)})},clean:function(b){return a(b)[0]},errors:function(){var b=this.settings.errorClass.split(" ").join(".");return a(this.settings.errorElement+"."+b,this.errorContext)},reset:function(){this.successList=[],this.errorList=[],this.errorMap={},this.toShow=a([]),this.toHide=a([]),this.currentElements=a([])},prepareForm:function(){this.reset(),this.toHide=this.errors().add(this.containers)},prepareElement:function(a){this.reset(),this.toHide=this.errorsFor(a)},elementValue:function(b){var c,d=a(b),e=b.type;return"radio"===e||"checkbox"===e?a("input[name='"+b.name+"']:checked").val():"number"===e&&"undefined"!=typeof b.validity?b.validity.badInput?!1:d.val():(c=d.val(),"string"==typeof c?c.replace(/\r/g,""):c)},check:function(b){b=this.validationTargetFor(this.clean(b));var c,d,e,f=a(b).rules(),g=a.map(f,function(a,b){return b}).length,h=!1,i=this.elementValue(b);for(d in f){e={method:d,parameters:f[d]};try{if(c=a.validator.methods[d].call(this,i,b,e.parameters),"dependency-mismatch"===c&&1===g){h=!0;continue}if(h=!1,"pending"===c)return void(this.toHide=this.toHide.not(this.errorsFor(b)));if(!c)return this.formatAndAdd(b,e),!1}catch(j){throw this.settings.debug&&window.console&&console.log("Exception occurred when checking element "+b.id+", check the '"+e.method+"' method.",j),j}}if(!h)return this.objectLength(f)&&this.successList.push(b),!0},customDataMessage:function(b,c){return a(b).data("msg"+c.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+c.substring(1).toLowerCase())||a(b).data("msg")},customMessage:function(a,b){var c=this.settings.messages[a];return c&&(c.constructor===String?c:c[b])},findDefined:function(){for(var a=0;a<arguments.length;a++)if(void 0!==arguments[a])return arguments[a];return void 0},defaultMessage:function(b,c){return this.findDefined(this.customMessage(b.name,c),this.customDataMessage(b,c),!this.settings.ignoreTitle&&b.title||void 0,a.validator.messages[c],"<strong>Warning: No message defined for "+b.name+"</strong>")},formatAndAdd:function(b,c){var d=this.defaultMessage(b,c.method),e=/\$?\{(\d+)\}/g;"function"==typeof d?d=d.call(this,c.parameters,b):e.test(d)&&(d=a.validator.format(d.replace(e,"{$1}"),c.parameters)),this.errorList.push({message:d,element:b,method:c.method}),this.errorMap[b.name]=d,this.submitted[b.name]=d},addWrapper:function(a){return this.settings.wrapper&&(a=a.add(a.parent(this.settings.wrapper))),a},defaultShowErrors:function(){var a,b,c;for(a=0;this.errorList[a];a++)c=this.errorList[a],this.settings.highlight&&this.settings.highlight.call(this,c.element,this.settings.errorClass,this.settings.validClass),this.showLabel(c.element,c.message);if(this.errorList.length&&(this.toShow=this.toShow.add(this.containers)),this.settings.success)for(a=0;this.successList[a];a++)this.showLabel(this.successList[a]);if(this.settings.unhighlight)for(a=0,b=this.validElements();b[a];a++)this.settings.unhighlight.call(this,b[a],this.settings.errorClass,this.settings.validClass);this.toHide=this.toHide.not(this.toShow),this.hideErrors(),this.addWrapper(this.toShow).show()},validElements:function(){return this.currentElements.not(this.invalidElements())},invalidElements:function(){return a(this.errorList).map(function(){return this.element})},showLabel:function(b,c){var d,e,f,g=this.errorsFor(b),h=this.idOrName(b),i=a(b).attr("aria-describedby");g.length?(g.removeClass(this.settings.validClass).addClass(this.settings.errorClass),g.html(c)):(g=a("<"+this.settings.errorElement+">").attr("id",h+"-error").addClass(this.settings.errorClass).html(c||""),d=g,this.settings.wrapper&&(d=g.hide().show().wrap("<"+this.settings.wrapper+"/>").parent()),this.labelContainer.length?this.labelContainer.append(d):this.settings.errorPlacement?this.settings.errorPlacement(d,a(b)):d.insertAfter(b),g.is("label")?g.attr("for",h):0===g.parents("label[for='"+h+"']").length&&(f=g.attr("id"),i?i.match(new RegExp("\b"+f+"\b"))||(i+=" "+f):i=f,a(b).attr("aria-describedby",i),e=this.groups[b.name],e&&a.each(this.groups,function(b,c){c===e&&a("[name='"+b+"']",this.currentForm).attr("aria-describedby",g.attr("id"))}))),!c&&this.settings.success&&(g.text(""),"string"==typeof this.settings.success?g.addClass(this.settings.success):this.settings.success(g,b)),this.toShow=this.toShow.add(g)},errorsFor:function(b){var c=this.idOrName(b),d=a(b).attr("aria-describedby"),e="label[for='"+c+"'], label[for='"+c+"'] *";return d&&(e=e+", #"+d.replace(/\s+/g,", #")),this.errors().filter(e)},idOrName:function(a){return this.groups[a.name]||(this.checkable(a)?a.name:a.id||a.name)},validationTargetFor:function(a){return this.checkable(a)&&(a=this.findByName(a.name).not(this.settings.ignore)[0]),a},checkable:function(a){return/radio|checkbox/i.test(a.type)},findByName:function(b){return a(this.currentForm).find("[name='"+b+"']")},getLength:function(b,c){switch(c.nodeName.toLowerCase()){case"select":return a("option:selected",c).length;case"input":if(this.checkable(c))return this.findByName(c.name).filter(":checked").length}return b.length},depend:function(a,b){return this.dependTypes[typeof a]?this.dependTypes[typeof a](a,b):!0},dependTypes:{"boolean":function(a){return a},string:function(b,c){return!!a(b,c.form).length},"function":function(a,b){return a(b)}},optional:function(b){var c=this.elementValue(b);return!a.validator.methods.required.call(this,c,b)&&"dependency-mismatch"},startRequest:function(a){this.pending[a.name]||(this.pendingRequest++,this.pending[a.name]=!0)},stopRequest:function(b,c){this.pendingRequest--,this.pendingRequest<0&&(this.pendingRequest=0),delete this.pending[b.name],c&&0===this.pendingRequest&&this.formSubmitted&&this.form()?(a(this.currentForm).submit(),this.formSubmitted=!1):!c&&0===this.pendingRequest&&this.formSubmitted&&(a(this.currentForm).triggerHandler("invalid-form",[this]),this.formSubmitted=!1)},previousValue:function(b){return a.data(b,"previousValue")||a.data(b,"previousValue",{old:null,valid:!0,message:this.defaultMessage(b,"remote")})}},classRuleSettings:{required:{required:!0},email:{email:!0},url:{url:!0},date:{date:!0},dateISO:{dateISO:!0},number:{number:!0},direccion:{direccion:!0},texto:{texto:!0},digits:{digits:!0},creditcard:{creditcard:!0}},addClassRules:function(b,c){b.constructor===String?this.classRuleSettings[b]=c:a.extend(this.classRuleSettings,b)},classRules:function(b){var c={},d=a(b).attr("class");return d&&a.each(d.split(" "),function(){this in a.validator.classRuleSettings&&a.extend(c,a.validator.classRuleSettings[this])}),c},attributeRules:function(b){var c,d,e={},f=a(b),g=b.getAttribute("type");for(c in a.validator.methods)"required"===c?(d=b.getAttribute(c),""===d&&(d=!0),d=!!d):d=f.attr(c),/min|max/.test(c)&&(null===g||/number|range|text/.test(g))&&(d=Number(d)),d||0===d?e[c]=d:g===c&&"range"!==g&&(e[c]=!0);return e.maxlength&&/-1|2147483647|524288/.test(e.maxlength)&&delete e.maxlength,e},dataRules:function(b){var c,d,e={},f=a(b);for(c in a.validator.methods)d=f.data("rule"+c.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+c.substring(1).toLowerCase()),void 0!==d&&(e[c]=d);return e},staticRules:function(b){var c={},d=a.data(b.form,"validator");return d.settings.rules&&(c=a.validator.normalizeRule(d.settings.rules[b.name])||{}),c},normalizeRules:function(b,c){return a.each(b,function(d,e){if(e===!1)return void delete b[d];if(e.param||e.depends){var f=!0;switch(typeof e.depends){case"string":f=!!a(e.depends,c.form).length;break;case"function":f=e.depends.call(c,c)}f?b[d]=void 0!==e.param?e.param:!0:delete b[d]}}),a.each(b,function(d,e){b[d]=a.isFunction(e)?e(c):e}),a.each(["minlength","maxlength"],function(){b[this]&&(b[this]=Number(b[this]))}),a.each(["rangelength","range"],function(){var c;b[this]&&(a.isArray(b[this])?b[this]=[Number(b[this][0]),Number(b[this][1])]:"string"==typeof b[this]&&(c=b[this].replace(/[\[\]]/g,"").split(/[\s,]+/),b[this]=[Number(c[0]),Number(c[1])]))}),a.validator.autoCreateRanges&&(b.min&&b.max&&(b.range=[b.min,b.max],delete b.min,delete b.max),b.minlength&&b.maxlength&&(b.rangelength=[b.minlength,b.maxlength],delete b.minlength,delete b.maxlength)),b},normalizeRule:function(b){if("string"==typeof b){var c={};a.each(b.split(/\s/),function(){c[this]=!0}),b=c}return b},addMethod:function(b,c,d){a.validator.methods[b]=c,a.validator.messages[b]=void 0!==d?d:a.validator.messages[b],c.length<3&&a.validator.addClassRules(b,a.validator.normalizeRule(b))},methods:{required:function(b,c,d){if(!this.depend(d,c))return"dependency-mismatch";if("select"===c.nodeName.toLowerCase()){var e=a(c).val();return e&&e.length>0}return this.checkable(c)?this.getLength(b,c)>0:a.trim(b).length>0},email:function(a,b){return this.optional(b)||/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/.test(a)},url:function(a,b){return this.optional(b)||/^(https?|s?ftp):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i.test(a)},date:function(a,b){return this.optional(b)||!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(a).toString())},dateISO:function(a,b){return this.optional(b)||/^\d{4}[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/.test(a)},number:function(a,b){return this.optional(b)||/^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)?(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(a)},direccion:function(a,b){return this.optional(b)||/^[A-Za-z0-9\#\-\s\xF1\xD1\xC1\xC9\xCD\xBF\xDA\xE1\xE9\xED\xF3\xFA]+$/.test(a)},texto:function(a,b){return this.optional(b)||/^[A-Za-z\s\xF1\xD1\xC1\xC9\xCD\xBF\xDA\xE1\xE9\xED\xF3\xFA]+$/.test(a)},digits:function(a,b){return this.optional(b)||/^\d+$/.test(a)},creditcard:function(a,b){if(this.optional(b))return"dependency-mismatch";if(/[^0-9 \-]+/.test(a))return!1;var c,d,e=0,f=0,g=!1;if(a=a.replace(/\D/g,""),a.length<13||a.length>19)return!1;for(c=a.length-1;c>=0;c--)d=a.charAt(c),f=parseInt(d,10),g&&(f*=2)>9&&(f-=9),e+=f,g=!g;return e%10===0},minlength:function(b,c,d){var e=a.isArray(b)?b.length:this.getLength(a.trim(b),c);return this.optional(c)||e>=d},maxlength:function(b,c,d){var e=a.isArray(b)?b.length:this.getLength(a.trim(b),c);return this.optional(c)||d>=e},rangelength:function(b,c,d){var e=a.isArray(b)?b.length:this.getLength(a.trim(b),c);return this.optional(c)||e>=d[0]&&e<=d[1]},min:function(a,b,c){return this.optional(b)||a>=c},max:function(a,b,c){return this.optional(b)||c>=a},range:function(a,b,c){return this.optional(b)||a>=c[0]&&a<=c[1]},equalTo:function(b,c,d){var e=a(d);return this.settings.onfocusout&&e.unbind(".validate-equalTo").bind("blur.validate-equalTo",function(){a(c).valid()}),b===e.val()},remote:function(b,c,d){if(this.optional(c))return"dependency-mismatch";var e,f,g=this.previousValue(c);return this.settings.messages[c.name]||(this.settings.messages[c.name]={}),g.originalMessage=this.settings.messages[c.name].remote,this.settings.messages[c.name].remote=g.message,d="string"==typeof d&&{url:d}||d,g.old===b?g.valid:(g.old=b,e=this,this.startRequest(c),f={},f[c.name]=b,a.ajax(a.extend(!0,{url:d,mode:"abort",port:"validate"+c.name,dataType:"json",data:f,context:e.currentForm,success:function(d){var f,h,i,j=d===!0||"true"===d;e.settings.messages[c.name].remote=g.originalMessage,j?(i=e.formSubmitted,e.prepareElement(c),e.formSubmitted=i,e.successList.push(c),delete e.invalid[c.name],e.showErrors()):(f={},h=d||e.defaultMessage(c,"remote"),f[c.name]=g.message=a.isFunction(h)?h(b):h,e.invalid[c.name]=!0,e.showErrors(f)),g.valid=j,e.stopRequest(c,j)}},d)),"pending")}}}),a.format=function(){throw"$.format has been deprecated. Please use $.validator.format instead."};var b,c={};a.ajaxPrefilter?a.ajaxPrefilter(function(a,b,d){var e=a.port;"abort"===a.mode&&(c[e]&&c[e].abort(),c[e]=d)}):(b=a.ajax,a.ajax=function(d){var e=("mode"in d?d:a.ajaxSettings).mode,f=("port"in d?d:a.ajaxSettings).port;return"abort"===e?(c[f]&&c[f].abort(),c[f]=b.apply(this,arguments),c[f]):b.apply(this,arguments)}),a.extend(a.fn,{validateDelegate:function(b,c,d){return this.bind(c,function(c){var e=a(c.target);return e.is(b)?d.apply(e,arguments):void 0})}})});
```

```css
.has-float-label{display:block;position:relative}.has-float-label label,.has-float-label>span{position:absolute;cursor:text;font-size:75%;opacity:1;-webkit-transition:all .2s;transition:all .2s;top:-.5em;left:12px;z-index:3;line-height:1;padding:0 1px}.has-float-label label::after,.has-float-label>span::after{content:" ";display:block;position:absolute;background:#fff;height:2px;top:50%;left:-.2em;right:-.2em;z-index:-1}.has-float-label .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder{opacity:1;-webkit-transition:all .2s;transition:all .2s}.has-float-label .form-control::-moz-placeholder{opacity:1;transition:all .2s}.has-float-label .form-control:-ms-input-placeholder{opacity:1;transition:all .2s}.has-float-label .form-control::placeholder{opacity:1;-webkit-transition:all .2s;transition:all .2s}.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::-webkit-input-placeholder{opacity:0}.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::-moz-placeholder{opacity:0}.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus):-ms-input-placeholder{opacity:0}.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::placeholder{opacity:0}.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)+*{font-size:150%;opacity:.5;top:.3em;font-weight:400}.input-group .has-float-label{display:table-cell}.input-group .has-float-label .form-control{border-radius:4px}.input-group .has-float-label:not(:last-child) .form-control{border-bottom-right-radius:0;border-top-right-radius:0}.input-group .has-float-label:not(:first-child) .form-control{border-bottom-left-radius:0;border-top-left-radius:0;margin-left:-1px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
 <span class="has-float-label">
  <input style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px" class="form-control required digits" id="numero" name="numero" type="text" placeholder="   " tabindex=2/>
  <label style="font-family:Arial; font-size:13px" for="numero">Número Identificación *</label>
 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es mostrar el codigo y decir que version de bootstrap usas

Comment: Gracias, Ya lo anexo.

Comment: Listo ya agregue el codigo, agradesco su ayuda. @Franklin'jGil'z

Comment: No puedo reproducir el error con el ejemplo que publicaste.

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo la función de la `label` junto al `input`, para utilizar el `placeholder` ponle lo que quieras que aparezca dentro del campo `placeholder`. Por otro lado, algo del CSS/JS genera problemas porque hace desaparecer el `placeholder` hasta que el campo gana el **focus** (en el siguiente código he borrado todo el JS/CSS).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
 <span class="has-float-label">
  <input style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px" class="form-control required digits" id="numero" name="numero" type="text" placeholder="Número de identificación" tabindex=2/>
 </span>
</div>
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.